# Modify layer colors of mapbox style using setPaintProperty

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox's outdoor v10 as my base map style. I am trying to update colors of specific layers but am running into errors.

I would expect this to update the roads to be red...

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: this.mapContainer,
  center: homePoint.geometry.coordinates,
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v10',
  interactive: false,
});    

map.on('load', function () {
  map.setPaintProperty('road-primary','fill-color', 'rgb(255,0,0)')
}
```

But then I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `road-primary` layer included in the outdoor style is of type `line`. So your `setPaintProperty` call should modify the `line-color` instead of the `fill-color`:

```
map.setPaintProperty('road-primary', 'line-color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
```

See the documentation here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#paint-line-line-color